# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while fetching huge amount of data from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetch data from an API using this code in react native. I get an error: **Unexpected end of JSON input**.

However, when I try to fetch from another API, such as: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees, it works properly. The difference between the two API's is that the first one returns huge amount of data. I do not know whether this can affect the result or not.

The API that is not working is: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

Please, take a look at my code:

```
 fetch("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("DATA: ", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
```

Comment: The JSON from that URL is valid. Have you checked the developer tools to see what was actually returned from your `fetch()` call?

Comment: No CORS headers are present when I load that URL, so that could be your problem.

Comment: What are CORS headers?

Comment: @Pointy The fetch's response when printed shows some information about the response header. Like for example it is 200 OK response and so on. When I try to say response.json(), it prints the error I mentioned

Comment: If you're trying to fetch from a site that's different from your own domain, the browser will insist that the target site explicitly allows such activity. It does that via cross-origin headers (CORS). Check the response body to see what it looks like.